# How to add Conflict handler (or ConflictHook) in AEM 6.1

Tags: adobe, aem, jackrabbit-oak, aem-6

Jackrabbit Oak has introduced Conflict handlers and ConflictHooks. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to add such handler / hook in AEM application. I tried to find something in documentation, but without any success.